# Selecting elements and its parent, with all Strings that it got

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, selector

I using Capybara for writing acceptance tests. And I want to make sure that my element is visible on a page. How i can select element and with all Strings that it got?

A page looks like this

```
<tr>
              <td class="pl-4">ABC</td>
              <td class="text">5000$</td>
              <td>
                <span class="spanclass">
                  SpanClassExample
                </span>

                  <br>
                  <a class="badge badge-secondary" href="//.../">CLASS</a>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right">NAME1</td>
              <td>NAME2</td>
              <td>NAME3</td>
              <td>NAME4</td>
              <td>NAME5</td>
</tr>
```

For now I use this method

> page.all(".text-right", text: 'NAME1')[0].visible?

But I need to find element with all strings that it got

> NAME1
>                 NAME2
>                 NAME3
>                 NAME4
>                 NAME5).

And also this element

> (span class="spanclass" SpanClassExample /span>)

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to get.  The 'NAME2 NAME3 NAME4 NAME5' are not inside elements with the class `.text-right` so your statement that the element has those strings doesn't make sense. Also, by default Capybara will only find visible elements so checking `visible?` also doesn't make sense (`visible?` also only returns true or false so just calling it doesn't actually verify anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest adding an ID to the row, for instance:

```
<tr id="thing-<%= thing.id %>">
```

So that you can later do:

```
within("tr#thing-#{thing.id}") do
  expect(page).to have_content thing.name # or whatever you want to look for
end
```